# Manually typing in filename ifstream

Tags: c++, file-io

Can I manually type in the file name inside of the terminal?

For example, the program will ask me which file I want to open up. I'll manually type in "test.txt" and it'll open up `test.txt`. However, my compiler is issuing the following error:

```
no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(std::string&)'
```

My code:

```
int main() {
    string input;
    cout << "Please enter the name of the file\n";
    cout << "Input: ";
    getline (cin, input);

    ifstream file (input);

    if (file.is_open()) {
        // blah
    } else {
        // blah
    }
}
```

How can I manually type in the text file name?

Comment: @JonnyHenly Well, it says: `no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(std::string&)'`

Comment: Did you include the proper header file for `ifstream`? The include should be `include <fstream>`.

Comment: @JonnyHenly `#include <fstream>`? If so, yes, I included it.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Oh. That worked! What the hay..

Comment: @JerryCoffin How do I give you points for answering my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an older (pre-C++11) compiler, you'll have to use:

```
ifstream file (input.c_str());
```

Although the file name was a string-like thing, and C++98 had `std::string`, they didn't put two and two together (so to speak), so in C++98 the string-like thing to specify the name of a file you wanted to open had to be specified as a `char const *` (i.e., a C-style string) rather than an `std::string`.

I predict it's purely a matter of time before supporting only `char const *` and `std::string` as the name looks (at least close to) equally silly--once we're accustomed to using ranges, it'll be obvious that it should really just be some range of character-like things.

Comment: Thank you for your help! :D